# What is the meaning of "how" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "how" in the following sentence,
( Source:SMALL BAD WOLF written by SEAN TAYLOR illustrated by JAN LEWIS )

> "He's going to **grow up bad to the bone**, just like his father!" "He
>   won't unless you teach him **how**," huffed Mother Wolf. "I thought
>   growing up a big bad wolf was going to be full of nippy, zippy
>   adventures like it is in the stories," complained the Small Bad Wolf.
>
> ?

Does it mean " *"if he grow up, he may be bad boy, just like his father!" "He will not be bad boy unless you teach him that way," huffed Mother Wolf.* "
?

Does "He's going to grow up bad to the bone" mean "He's going to grow up and He's will be bad to the bone(bad boy)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He will grow up to be bad to the bone,  as his father is bad to the bone.

He won't grow up to be bad to the bone, not unless you teach him how to be bad to the bone.

In other words, Mother Wolf's view is that he will grow up to be good if he is not taught how to be bad to the bone.  And if not "good", at least not "bad to the bone".